# Save product as favorite product with jquery cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies

In a webshop product page, i would like to save the product as favorite with jquery cookie.

But when i click save, i always get the message, that the products has been saved as favorit, also if the product has been saved. I never get the massege, that this procduct is already on the favorits list.

```
$('#favorite_button').click(function()
{
     var cookie_message, item_id, most_van;//most_van means, that the cookie exists with the procut ID
     item_id = <?php echo $kat_id  ?>; // product ID
     var cookie_val = $.cookie("kedvenc_termek_cookie");
     if (cookie_val)
     {
         most_van = cookie_val.split("|");
     }
     else
     {
         most_van = [];
     }
     if ($.inArray(item_id, most_van) === -1)
     {
         most_van.push(item_id);
         $.removeCookie('kedvenc_termek_cookie');
         $.cookie('kedvenc_termek_cookie', most_van.join("|"), { expires: 7, path: "/" });
         cookie_message = "Product saved as favorite.";
     }
     else
     {
         cookie_message = "This product is alredy on your favorite list.";
     }
     $('#FavoritItemModalResult').html(cookie_message);
     $('#FavoritItemModal').modal('show');
     setTimeout(function()
     {
        $('#FavoritItemModal').modal('hide');
     }, 3000 );
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your cookie `Split()` delimiter is incorrect. It's `;`, not `|`:

```
var cookies = [];
document.cookie.split(/; */).forEach(function(cookieraw){
  var cookie  = this.split('=');
  var name    = cookieraw[0];//print it 
  var value   = cookieraw[1]; //print it 

  cookies.push({ "name": name, "value": value });
});
```

Comment: I change | to ;, but i still have the same problem.